# Php and iOS Encryption RNCryptor

Tags: php, ios

I have been trying to encrypt data from php and send it to iOS (I use the RNCryptor library).

I have read through the [github Data-Format](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor/wiki/Data-Format)
and developed this algorithm on php.

```
function encrypt($data, $key)
{
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

    $keySalt  = '12345678';
    $hmacSalt = '12345678';

    $_key = pbkdf2('SHA1', $key, $keySalt , 10000, 32, true);
    $_hmacKey = pbkdf2('SHA1', $key, $hmacSalt, 10000, 32, true);

    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $_key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

    $data = base64_encode(chr(2).chr(0).$keySalt.$hmacSalt.$iv.$ciphertext.hash_hmac('SHA256',$ciphertext,$_hmacKey, true));

    return $data;
}
```

However, when the Data is sent to the php. I received such error in the iOS debugging tool:

```
Error Domain=net.robnapier.RNCryptManager Code=-4300 "The operation coulnd't be completed. (net.robnapier.RNCryptManager error - 4300.)";
```

I've look at many website. I've also followed the github website step-by-step, but still unable to find the right answer.

Comment: chr(2).chr(0) should be -->  chr(2).chr(1) since you are using password (check the last Data format for RNCryptor)

Comment: I did that too, but still no hope. :(